# Enable macro on a single workbook

Tags: excel, vba

So, I'm working on an automation project and have stumbled on a roadblock because I can't call anything on a downloaded Excel file.

When I try opening the Excel file manually, its VB Editor is disabled... All other opened Excel files have it enabled.

I'm using below for downloading/opening the said Excel (XLSX) file.

```
Sub GetLogins()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
NavSheet.Unprotect [pw]
Dim LoginWkbk As Workbook, LoginWksht As Worksheet
Dim WinHTTPRequest As Object, ADOStream As Object
Dim URL As String
Dim FileRev As Long, LastRow As Long, x As Long
Dim ts As Double

ts = Timer
FileRev = [Revision] ' The current logins file revision
FileRev = FileRev + 1 ' Check for the next revision. Hah!

TryAgain:
If Password = "" Then AcctLoginsForm.Show ' Password not (yet?) supplied

' Second line of security.
If Username = "" Or Password = "" Then
    ' This checks if the user provided the complete information required.
    ' If they didn't we would clear the admin logins sheet of any information that was in there.
    Call ClearAcctsSheet
    MsgBox "Insufficient information submitted.", vbOKOnly, "Window_Title"
    GoTo ExitSub
End If

' The logins file URL
URL = "https://mysecreturl" & FileRev & ".xlsx"
Set WinHTTPRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

    With WinHTTPRequest
        ' "GET" command with username and password
        .Open "GET", URL, False, Username, Password
        .Send

        Select Case .Status
            Case 401
                ' Incorrect credentials.
                If MsgBox("Incorrect Username/Password supplied. Try again?", vbYesNo, "Window_Title") = vbYes Then
                    Call ClearAcctsSheet
                    Password = ""
                    GoTo TryAgain
                Else
                    GoTo ExitSub
                End If
            Case 404
                ' The next revision is not yet uploaded, so we set to download the previous revision
                FileRev = FileRev - 1
                GoTo TryAgain
            Case 200
                ' Set the "Revision" named range to the current file revision
                [Revision] = FileRev
        End Select

        Set ADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        ADOStream.Open
        ADOStream.Type = 1
        ADOStream.Write .ResponseBody
        ADOStream.SaveToFile Environ$("temp") & "\logins.xlsx", 2 ' Save the file in the temp file overwriting if the file exists
        ADOStream.Close
    End With

    ' Need to clear out the Accounts Sheet fields before populating it with the new credentials
    AcctsSheet.Range("A:C").ClearContents

    Set LoginWkbk = Workbooks.Open(Environ$("temp") & "\logins.xlsx")
    Set LoginWksht = LoginWkbk.Sheets(1)
    LastRow = LoginWksht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' Last row. Duh.
    For x = 1 To LastRow
        ' Copy-pasting the information from the logins file crashes Excel, hence this for-loop.
        AcctsSheet.Range("A" & x).Value = LoginWksht.Range("A" & x).Value
        AcctsSheet.Range("B" & x).Value = LoginWksht.Range("G" & x).Value
        AcctsSheet.Range("C" & x).Value = LoginWksht.Range("H" & x).Value
        Application.StatusBar = "Extraction complete. Time elapsed: " & Round(Timer - ts, 2)
        If LoginWksht.Range("A" & x).Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x
    LoginWkbk.Close False ' Close the logins file
    Kill Environ$("temp") & "\logins.xlsx" ' Delete the logins file
    [DateToday] = Format(Now, "m/d/yyyy") ' Set the "DateToday" named range to the current day.

ExitSub:
NavSheet.Protect [pw]
NavSheet.Activate
ThisWorkbook.Save
SetToNothing WinHTTPRequest, ADOStream, LoginWkbk, LoginWksht
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I can open the Excel file with `Workbooks.Open`, but the opened XLSX file is not listed in the VBAProject window so I can't call anything on the sheet.

Has anyone encountered this here? Can we force-enable the macro settings on a single workbook?

Answer (score 2):

A `.xlsx` file cannot have macros. In my test, the VB editor is not disabled, there are just no macros in the file to show. If you have macros enabled in Excel settings, then the workbook may still need to be in a Trusted Location for Excel to allow macros to run.

Comment: Hi Paul, sorry for the confusion. I'm not trying to have a macro on the `.xlsx` file, I'm just trying to refer to its cells for copying. See the for-loop after `Workbooks.Open`, that LoginWkbk object is still `Nothing` after opening the file...

Tried adding it also to Trusted Location, but to no avail. Thanks, though.